# Set Scroll Bar of Iframe to Bottom

Tags: html, iframe

In my application I have the Iframe that has some log file content. Since I will always be interested in the latest logs. I always want to keep the scroll bar to the bottom. How can I achieve it.

```
    <IFRAME src="/results/show_client_log?testinstanceId=<%=params[:testinstanceId]%>&clientIp=<%=params[:clientIp]%>" id= "frame" style="width:100%;" height=500px scrolling="yes"></IFRAME>
```

This the code that enables the scrollbar to iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Does adding this to style section in your iframe work?

```
overflow: auto;
```

or maybe even

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

or

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```